# add a section in wordpress theme to upload image and process it

Tags: theme-customizer

I want to add a section in wordpress theme in which user can upload an image and then this image sent to server and process and result show to user in that page. is it possible to so this in wordpress?

Comment: Yes, but please note this is a site for helping with minor code modifications rather than providing detailed code. You may want to search for themes or plugins that already do what you're trying to achieve, or hire a developer if you're not comfortable editing code and trying things out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show image on a main page or an inner page then go to pages and add featured image from there,
Or if you want to show image on a blog post then head over to posts and then create a new post and upload a featured image in that.
And then publish/update your post/page.

Comment: my problem is something else. I want to have a section that user can upload an image this image is processed in the server for example shoes how old is the person in the pic and then show the result to user

Comment: To have a section where a user can upload his/her image, you can use custom fields or advanced custom fields to create a upload button. But to recognise the age of user from a photo you have to use machine learning to know the age of user.